# calling javascripts within a jQuery dialog

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm having trouble accessing javascripts within a jQuery dialog.

For example, page A calls a page B which is displayed within a jQuery Dialog.

On page B, I'm trying to implement a jQuery Datepicker. 
However, it doesn't seem to work no matter where I put the Datepicker code (in page A or in page B).

Any one know how to get call javascripts within a jQuery dialog?

Comment: Please post some code of Page A and Page B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I finally figured it out. I had to put in the javascript within the open method of the UI dialog call.